# How does blockchain.info generate the mnemonic passphrase?

Tags: javascript, passwords, password-recovery

When you sign up for a wallet at blockchain.info (https://blockchain.info/wallet/new) they generate a long mnemonic (diceware style) passphrase from your short (10+ character) password. That long mnemonic passphrase can then be used to recover your lost password.

I want to try something similar but I don't really how it works.

Is there a name for it?

Are there any open source examples?

Comment: Can you show us a picture, or some code? This question as-is is unlikely to help anybody. If you're looking for a library it's off-topic.

Comment: it's probably easier to just check it out. Go to: https://blockchain.info/wallet/new - just type a password and the captcha and you'll see the mnemonic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know exactly how they do it behind the scenes, but I would guess that the ten words are pretty much arbitrary, they just use it as a decryption key, and then encrpypt the decryption key and use that result to look up the rows.

Something like:

```
SELECT key, username, password FROM table WHERE key = ENCRYPT("around guide speed slings 
dislodge arise espe matthias rosenfeld unmade defy graef grumbles hamed haw hermit 
hobbes");

//returns
//key="ABC123"
//username="DEF456"
//password="GHI789"
```

Then, they have their decrypt function, which takes what is to be decrypted and what is the decryption key -

```
function DECRYPT($encrypted, $decryption_key) { //do stuff
}

DECRYPT("DEF456", "around guide speed ... hobbes") //returns plain text username
DECRYPT("GHI789", "around guide speed ... hobbes") //returns plain text password
```